# Installing visual studio 6 on windows 10

Tags: c++, installation, windows-10, visual-c++-6

In Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 it was possible to install **visual studio 6** by among others creating a dummy file '**msjava.dll**' in '**%windir%**' and possibly '**%windir%\system32**', so that the vs6 installation programme did not interrupt for installing the **virtual machine for java**.

This measure did not succeed for me at two pcs upgraded to **windows 10**, one from **windows 7 prof 64 bit** and one from **windows 8.1 home 64 bit**.

Can anybody tell me how this might function in windows 10?

Comment: VS 6!? Upgrade much ;)

Comment: Installing a compiler without the [stack protector feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection) (`-fstack-protector` in GCC, `/GS` in MSVC++) in 2015 is not good.

Comment: I haven't heard many good things about Windows 10 yet, but this is good news.

Comment: Cool, there are others still using Visual Studio 6! Although I use it for VB6 (_shh...._) :) +1

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils My shop is stuck using VB6.

Answer (score 2):

Running Visual C++ 6.0 on Windows 8.1, 8 and 10.

you have to follow those steps :

- download the SP6 pack : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9183
- uncompress the VS6sp61.cab package in a directory (with Winrar or
  7zip for example)
- copy files from the SP6 in the MSDEV directory    (replace common
  files) in `%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDev98\Bin\` folder

  - Run `msdevP.exe` or `msdevS.exe` instead of the original `msdev.exe`

Source : http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-8&faq=152

source 2 : http://blog.wavosaur.com/run-visual-c-6-on-windows-8/

Comment: How about instructions for installation?  The VS6 installation hangs at the very end.  It seems to install most components, but then attempting to install SP6 fails too.

Comment: These instructions helped me overcome the problem with the installation freezing.  Specifically the instructions for the custom install options were important.

Answer (score 2):

I kept my old Win 95 and old Win XP pc's. Anytime I want to use VC++ 6.0, I fire up one of those and use it.  Otherwise on Win 10-64bit I use "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express". It's really old and dated but works, np.